# Reproducing Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature using CSS

Tags: css

In Chrome if you right click an element and select "Inspect Element" the developer tools will open and your element will be highlighted in a blue color. I'd like to reproduce that with my own CSS style. Here's an example:

[image: Example]

Notice that it is actually making the foreground color of the element a transparent blue. Naively changing the background-color doesn't work nearly as well since you'd also have to change the font color and you wouldn't be able to highlight images.

At the moment the only way that I can figure out how to reproduce the foreground mask effect is by creating an absolute positioned element on top of the original with the exact same dimensions. This seems a bit clunky and I wonder if there's some way to do this purely in CSS?

Comment: You _might_ be able to do something similar with the absolute position you mentioned on a pseudo-element in css, such as `::after` and `::before` just be sure to set a high z-index and make it a transparent element.

Comment: Is this question #4,000,000?